# Remove two subfolders and change plusses to dashes in the URL using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm in the process of migrating a website from an old CMS to Wordpress.   The way that some of the old URLs were:

`http://www.example.com/tags/tagged/tag/tag+name`

For Wordpress, I need it to be the following URL:

`http://www.example.com/tag/tag-name`

So I need to remove the `/tags/tagged` sub-directories and also change the `+` signs to `-` signs.   Is there any way to do this with .htaccess?

Comment: How _generic_ do you need this to be? Are `/tags/tagged` any two subdirectories? Or some specific subdirectories or a singular specific URL-path? In the `/tag/tag-name` part, it looks like the preceding subdirectory matches the first part of the final path segment - is that significant? "change the + signs to - signs" - could there be more than one `+` sign? Or is it literally just `first+second`? Or even hardcoded `tag+name`??

Comment: @MrWhite in the WordPress example `tag` is literal and `tag-name` is a URL slug.   I'm taking it as `tags/tagged/tag` is literal and `tag+name` is a URL slug with possibly multiple plusses.

Comment: @MrWhite - the /tags/tagged was created by an external plugin from the old CMS, theyre not actual subdirectories. If a tag name has a space in it, the old CMS would automatically added the + sign between the words WordPress uses the - sign for their slugs

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something similar to the answer to [mod_rewrite: replace underscores with dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279681/mod-rewrite-replace-underscores-with-dashes) on StackOverflow:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/?tags/tagged/tag/[^/]*)\+([^/]*)$ $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^/?tags/tagged(/tag/[^/\+]*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

The first rule should loop multiple times because it uses the `N` or "next" flag.  It should change one plus to a a dash each time.

Once there are no pluses left, the second rule should trigger.  It will remove the extra directories because the first parenthesis  only includes the `tag` directory.  Then it will issue the redirect.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working/redirecting. I'm getting a 404 error :(

Comment: What if you remove the `\+` from the last rule?   That should issue the redirect without fixing the plusses.   If that doesn't work, I think you don't have the code in the correct file or something.